# Checking my reasoning for $HK/K \cong H/H\cap K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I'm studying for a test and I just wanted to check if my reasoning behind the proof of $HK/K \cong H/H\cap K$ was correct.

The whole statement is: $G$ is a finite group. $H, K\leq G$ and $HK$ is a group and $K\trianglelefteq HK$. Then $HK/K \cong H/H\cap K$

So $K\trianglelefteq HK$ by hypothesis, and so we can take $\varphi: H \longrightarrow HK/K$ by $\varphi(h)=hK$. All we need to show is that $\varphi$ is surjective and that $\ker\varphi=H\cap K$ and then by first isomorphism theorem we have our proof. What I want to check is my reasoning, shown below:

By Lagrange's theorem, $|HK/K|=|HK|/|K|=|H||K|/|K|=|H|$, which just means that we have $|H|$ distinct cosets of size $|K|$. Since our mapping takes $H\longrightarrow HK/K$, the size of the domain and our codomain are the same, so the mapping is surjective (since every coset has a preimage, because there are $|H|$ many cosets and $|H|$ many elements of $H$). $\ker\varphi=hK$ such that $h\in H$ and $h\in K$, but this is just $e$ (the identity), which is $H\cap K$, so $\ker\varphi=H\cap K$. Therefore by first isomorphism theorem we have $HK/K \cong H/H\cap K$.

If anyone could let me know if my reasoning behind this is correct. If not then I'm truly lost at how this proof works, so if I am wrong, explaining why would also help immensely.

**EDIT**: I've been told the cardinality argument I'm using isn't correct, I see that $|HK|=|H||K|/|H\cap K|$, so if you plugged it into $|HK|/|K|$ you get $|H|/|H\cap K|$ instead of what I got. I realize it looks stupid to even say that but I just wanted to try and prove it was surjective beyond just saying it was surjective because I don't think I would get full credit if I did that.

So would it suffice to say that $\varphi$ is surjective because $hkK=hK\in HK/K$ is $\varphi(h)$?

Comment: Your third paragraph is not correct: $HK$ is a union of $K$-cosets by definition, but how many there are depends on the size of $H\cap K$. The second isomorphism theorem concerns the case where you have a normal subgroup $K$ of a group $G$ and another subgroup $H\leq G$. The quotient map $q\colon G\to G/K$ restricts to give a homomorphism from $H$ to $G/K$, and the second isomorphism theorem just works out what the first isomorphism says about $q_{|H}$.

Comment: Is it a hypothesis that these subgroups are finite? Please state *all* hypotheses clearly.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes, sorry. I just finished editing that in

Comment: So it seems there is no finiteness hypothesis. Does your argument make sense?

Comment: @krm2233 ok, so the surjectivity has nothing to do with the cardinality of $HK/K$? I googled second isomorphism theorem, and some sources are saying $\varphi$ is surjective because $hkK=hK\in HK/K$ is $\varphi(h)$, is that really all you have to say? Is what I said about the kernel wrong as well?

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry, now it's added. yes, $G$ is supposed to be finite.

Comment: In your third paragraph the domain of $\varphi$ should be $H$, not $HK$.

Comment: Your computation in the fourth paragraph is incorrect. You have $|HK|=|H||K|$. The correct equality is $|HK||H\cap K|=|H||K|$.

Comment: @pyat as Arturo points out, at the level of cardinals, the identity is $|HK|.|H\cap K|=|H|.|K|$.

Comment: From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: *"A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."*

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I fixed the domain thing, it must have been a typo because in my writing i do have the domain as $H$, so apologies. But for the cardinality argument, then is it just $|HK|/|K|=(|HK|\cdot |H\cap K|)/(|K|\cdot |H\cap K|)=|H||K|/|(K||H\cap K|)=|H|/|H\cap K|$?

Comment: It's basic algebra you are messing up/struggling with. $|HK|/|K| = |H||K|/(|H\cap K||K|) = |H|/|H\cap K|$. But this whole messing around with cardinalities is a waste of time and effort. The result is just the Second Isomorphism Theorem with $HK$ playing the role of the group, $K$ the normal subgroup, and $H$ the other subgroup.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, so $|HK|/|K|=|H||K|/(|H\cap K||K|)=|H|/|H\cap K|$? you just isolated $|HK|$ in the equality $|HK|\cdot |H\cap K|=|H| |K|$ and then substituted... but is what I did not essentially the same? multiply top and bottom by $|H\cap K|$, but then since $|HK|\cdot |H\cap K|=|H||K|$ the top part changes and we're left with the bottom $|K|\cdot |H\cap K|$, then cancel terms and we get $|H|/|H\cap K|$.

Comment: Which means that you took at least two extra steps to do a simple algebraic substitution... *that isn't needed anyway* because you are trying to reprove (for some strange reason) the Second Isomorphism Theorem, and doing so unaccountably and unnecessarily restricting yourself to finite groups. Talk about struggling mightily to get next to nothing out of the effort...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin the whole reason I was even messing with the cardinalities was because I just wanted to show it was surjective. Other sources online simply state it's surjective because $hkK=hK\in HK/K$ is $\varphi(h)$, is that all you need to say? I just wanted to try to show it in a different way, but since what I said isn't correct it's fine I'll just say what that one source is saying.

Comment: You prove a map is surjective by showing every element of the codomain lies in the image. Given $(hk)K\in HK/K$, the element $h\in H$ maps to $hK$, and *trivially* $hK=hkK$. Which is part of the proof of the Second Isomorphism Theorem, which, for the $n$th time, you should be using instead of flailing as you are doing, not really managing to prove a restricted case of a theorem you should know.